# skip the soggy elbow and damp power window electronics

Tags: meaning-in-context

My problem is with the last of part of the last sentence (in the italicized paragraph) . I can't tell if "damp" is a verb here or a noun and what could it have to do with power windows ( if that's what the author means by "power window electronics" and also with soggy elbow )

I've look up the word damp and according to Webster it means "dampen" which means: to check or diminish the activity or vigor of ( of course Webster had several definitions for it, but the one that fits here I guess was that one. )

I know all the other words pretty much.

elbow: some kind of macaroni
sloggy: wet

I'm so confused. could someone paraphrase or rewrite that part ( if it can be done so, in fact) or provide an explanation which could make it easier for me to understand?

*What if you are on Taco Bell’s executive team? Although your
company’s roots are So-Cal, if you’re thinking like a customer, you’d fit
watertight overhangs over your drive-through windows in most other
locales. Customers in Sacramento might not care, but in Seattle don’t
you think they would prefer to skip the side order of soggy elbow and
damp power window electronics?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damp is just an adjective, meaning slightly wet.  It's a consequence of winding the window down in the rain, along with getting a soggy elbow.

If the overhang were larger, the rain would be kept off, customers' elbows wouldn't get soggy and the electric window mechanisms wouldn't get damp.

Comment: oh, I see. so the author is kind of making a joke by saying "side order"?

Comment: @MMMM Yes, it's something you get along with the meal you ordered.

Comment: Alright. I got my answer.